# login to remote using "mstsc /admin" with password

Tags: batch-file, remote-desktop, mstsc

I want to use `mstsc /admin` to login to a server silently. My batch file reads the code as

```
mstsc /v:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /admin
```

But it ask me to enter password. Can anyone help me to skip this step?

I went on to Google and found [this site](http://www.poshpete.com/powershell/passing-username-and-passwords-to-remote-desktop-rdp-automatically). But I am very new to this stuff (scripting) and could not understand what to do with given code. Is it a `vbscript` file? Can I do the same thing with a batch file. Please elaborate and I request you to spoon feed. This is not my arena but still I am pushed to fight without weapons.

My basic need is to kick off all users from a remote desktop except mine to perform some maintainable work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It became a popular question and I got a notification. I am sorry, I forgot to answer before which I should have done. I solved it long back.

```
net use \\10.100.110.120\C$ MyPassword /user:domain\username /persistent:Yes
```

Run it in a batch file and you should get what you are looking for.

Comment: Does not appear to work. Still prompts for username.

Comment: Did you replace the "domain\username", "MyPassword" and IP Address in above command with your values? Also make sure you have credentials of Admin.

Comment: Found an alternative (Tested in Win8): cmdkey /generic:"<server>" /user:"<user>" /pass:"<pass>"

Answer (score 58):

Re-posted as an answer:
Found an alternative (Tested in Win8):

```
cmdkey /generic:"<server>" /user:"<user>" /pass:"<pass>"
```

Run that and if you run:

```
mstsc /v:<server>
```

You should not get an authentication prompt.

Comment: It works, but the password becomes saved in your system.

Comment: @AndreSoares true, but you can delete it with cmdkey /delete:servername or ip. This procedure works in windows 7.

Comment: It helped me to create a solution for Windows 10. Thanks. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46617521/6186647).

Comment: PowerShell cleanup of all saved credentials if you have a lot `$remove = cmdkey /list | & { Process { If($_ -like "*Target=*"){$_.Split("=")[1].Trim()} } };
$remove | & { Process { cmdkey /delete:$_ } };`

Answer (score 11):

to be secured, you should execute 3 commands :

```
cmdkey /generic:"server-address" /user:"username" /pass:"password"
mstsc /v:server-address
cmdkey /delete:server-address
```

first command to save the credential

second command to open remote desktop

and the third command to delete the credential for security reason

all of these commands can be saved in a batch file(bat).
(if you save these command in a batch file, third command will not be executed until you close the remote desk)

Comment: There's a gotcha here though, if you delete it too quick with the third command before the first two finish, the connection with fail. It's best to wait and run the deletion after the connection is established already.

Comment: in response to the first comment, if you save these command in a batch file, third command will not be executed until you close the remote desk.

Comment: Does not work if the target server does not allow logging in with saved credentials

Answer (score 9):

the command posted by Milad and Sandy did not work for me with mstsc. i had to add TERMSRV to the /generic switch. i found this information here: https://gist.github.com/jdforsythe/48a022ee22c8ec912b7e

`cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/<server> /user:<username> /pass:<password>`

i could then use `mstsc /v:<server>` without getting prompted for the login.

Answer (score 7):

Same problem but @Angelo answer didn't work for me, because I'm using same server with different credentials. I used the approach below and tested it on Windows 10.

`cmdkey /add:server01 /user:<username> /pass:<password>`

Then used `mstsc /v:server01` to connect to the server.

The point is to use names instead of ip addresses to avoid conflict between credentials. If you don't have a DNS server locally accessible try `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.

Comment: PowerShell cleanup of all saved credentials if you have a lot `$remove = cmdkey /list | & { Process { If($_ -like "*Target=*"){$_.Split("=")[1].Trim()} } };
$remove | & { Process { cmdkey /delete:$_ } };`

Answer (score 0):

Save your username, password and sever name in an RDP file and run the RDP file from your script

Comment: You can do it as a batch file using this line 
    "mstsc C:\foo.rdp" and add any command line parameters you want

Comment: Also change "prompt for credentials:i:1" to "prompt for credentials:i:0" in C:\foo.rdp

Comment: What do you mean by command line parameters, can we get and example of how you define username and pw? @StevenAckley

Comment: Look down two posts.https://stackoverflow.com/a/27308310/2004122

Comment: Not sure why you downvoted me. This is a completely valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Command mentioned above didn't work for me (Windows 11)

```
cmdkey /generic:"server-address" /user:"username" /pass:"password"
```

When i listed the cmdkeys using the commad:

```
cmdkey /list
```

I saw, that a legacy target was added. Adding a specific TERMSRV-Target worked for me:

```
cmdkey /add:Domain:target=TERMSRV/<SERVER> /user:<DOMAIN>\<USER> /pass:<PASSWORD>
```